# Is Water S the only effective shot type against Gravios?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I wanted to know if any ammunition for the Heavy Bowgun, aside from Water S, are useful against Gravios. I thought about Pierce S, but couldn't find any good information about it on the wiki or somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, pierce ammo is fantastic against Gravios, especially if you can line up your shots so they go through his whole body from head to tail.

Pierce ammo works by travelling in (roughly) a straight line, and when it hits a monster (which deals damage), it continues through it, dealing damage the entire time. So using pierce ammo against very large monsters like Gravios will give you much better results than using it against something small like a Velocidrome.

In general though, Heavy Bowguns should stick to firing non-elemental shots (like Normal and Pierce), whereas elemental and status shots (Water S, Para S, etc) are better suited to the Light Bowgun. This is due to the way that raw and elemental/status damage are calculated -- in general, weapons that hit fast prefer more element/status, whereas weapons that hit slower prefer more raw.

If you want to really tear Gravios to shreds, get a light bowgun that can rapid fire Water S, such as the [Plesioth Drencher](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/weapon/lightbowgun/plesioth-drencher)!

Comment: I agree with you that LBG is better for Elemental Shots than HBG, but I don't agree with your reasoning why. The reason LBG is better for elemental shots is because rapid firing elemental shots deals *massive* damage. If you don't have a LBG that can RF the proper element, but you have a HBG which can fire that element, then you're better off with the HBG.

Comment: It's also because elemental isn't affected by motion values, which is the reason why rapid firing elemental shots deals such ridiculous damage